# I have an error when running apt-get update

Tags: linux, debian, apt

In my Jenkins pipeline, I am trying to run a build using the Docker image `maven:3.5.4-jdk-10-slim` as my Jenkins agent. Inside it, I run the command `apt-get update`. However, when I do, I get the following error:

```
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid InRelease [165 kB]
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138 NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9
```

I searched online for help on this error, and it was advised I add the following 2 commands before my update command so I can add the public keys for apt to verify:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 648ACFD622F3D138
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0E98404D386FA1D9
```

However, now I get a different error when running those commands:

```
E: gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation
```

I also searched for help on that error, and I was advised to run this before the 2 new commands : `apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg`

But I can't run `apt-get update`. How can I fix this?

Comment: I've not used the `maven` docker image, but on the [official image's home page](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven) for the `slim` image it states: *This image does not contain the common packages contained in the default tag and only contains the minimal packages needed to run maven. Unless you are working in an environment where only the maven image will be deployed and you have space constraints, we highly recommend using the default image of this repository.*. My guess is that you should switch to the default and that apt, gpg, and other necessary bits may be there ready and waiting.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. For me, the following had solved the issue.

I realized, that I was using a very old version of `docker:18-dind` to build images in my CI. This `18-dind` was more like a puppet, that built and pushed images. It was able to build images, except that based on Ubuntu 22, for example, [`eclipse-temurin`](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin).

I updated my Docker build puppet from `18-dind` to `20-dind` and it solved the issue.